# How can I suppress a stack-buffer-overflow from AddressSanitizer in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, boost-program-options, address-sanitizer

My app is using `boost::program_options` and it's triggering an AddressSanitizer "stack-buffer-overflow" while generating an error message from an exception.

I'm not worried about the boost bug - the functionality works and this is just in the command line parsing portion of a non-production app. However I'd like to suppress the AddressSanitizer message.

```
ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7fffe6ce7070 at pc 0x0000007406cd bp 0x7fffe6ce6fe0 sp 0x7fffe6ce6fd8
READ of size 8 at 0x7fffe6ce7070 thread T0
    #0 0x7406cc in std::_Head_base<0ul, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&, false>::_M_head(std::_Head_base<0ul, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&, false>&) /frc/toolchain6/include/c++/5.3.0/tuple:142
    #1 0x7406cc in _M_create_node /frc/toolchain6/include/c++/5.3.0/tuple:347
    #2 0x7403fd in std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::_M_emplace_hint_unique<std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&>, std::tuple<> >(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::piecewise_construct_t const&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&>&&, std::tuple<>&&) /frc/toolchain6/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_tree.h:2170
    #3 0xd5eff8 in boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const (/home/joe/myapp_workspace/myapp/myapp-debug+0xd5eff8)
    #4 0xd5c0dd in boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const (/home/joe/myapp_workspace/myapp/myapp-debug+0xd5c0dd)
    #5 0x58addf in main /home/joe/myapp_workspace/myapp/main.cpp:62
    #6 0x7fd7e056176c in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2176c)
    #7 0x436aa0  (/home/joe/myapp_workspace/myapp/myapp-debug+0x436aa0)
```

I've tried using the ASAN_OPTIONS suppression file method but that only seems to support a very short list of error types (such as "vptr_check" and "leak").

Comment: A stack overflow will most probably result in a segfault so I would suggest looking into how you can trap a SIGSEGV signal.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi, this isn't a true stack overflow in that sense of the term and the app does not crash with or without asan enabled. AddressSanitizer is detecting reading from memory out of bounds of the buffer but it isn't the traditional OS protected memory.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an easy way to suppress this error - Clang version of Asan has blacklisting mechanism but it's context insensitive so you'd have to disable memory checking in all usages of `std::string` which is highly undesirable.

One option is to use `-fsanitize-recover=address` compiler flag and add `halt_on_error=0` to your `ASAN_OPTIONS` environment variable (see [wiki](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) for details and note that recovery is only supported is relatively new GCC and Clang). This will continue execution after first error. You'll then be able to examine full Asan report and select what interests you.