# Building glib library with ASAN

Tags: linker, glibc, glib, address-sanitizer

i am working on building glib library with ASAN, gcc version is 6.3 .

I am able to compile and build glib library with ASAN. My configure command is :-

```
../configure  CC='/local/test/v6.3.0/bin/gcc' CXX='/local/test/v6.3.0/bin/g++' CFLAGS='-fPIC -O2 -fsanitize=address' CXXFLAGS='-fPIC -fsanitize=address' LDFLAGS='-L/local/test/v6.3.0/lib64 -lasan' LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/local/test/v6.3.0/lib64'  --enable-static=yes --prefix=/home/testing/debug_glib/glib-2.56.1/testing_glb --enable-libmount=no PYTHON=/local/test/pkgs/python/v2.7.6/bin/python --with-pcre=/home/testing/pcre_lib/pcre-8.20/pcre_library
```

Here when i try to use newly created glib library, I am hitting undefined reference to symbol issue :

```
$ /local/test/client_new/test_build/kkl/tools/kenzip -c dcltotb.tcl
/home/testing/lib/libglib-2.0.so: undefined symbol: __asan_option_detect_stack_use_after_return
```

I am linking ASAN library (-lasan) which has above symbol defined in it. Any thing missing here? Please help!
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "I am hitting undefined reference to symbol issue" - do you hit it when you link your executable or run it?

Comment: When i try to use new glib (which was built with ASAN by Running above configure command) in my application. i am hitting the issue.

Comment: So does the error happen when you link or when you run your program? Please provide exact command which triggers the error.

Comment: Here is the command : /local/test/client_new/test_build/kkl/tools/kenzip -c dcltotb.tcl                   ERROR: /local/test/client_new/lop/lib/libglib-2.0.so: undefined symbol: __asan_option_detect_stack_use_after_return

Comment: kenzip is executable created without asan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to correct your `LDFLAGS` to be

```
LDFLAGS=-fsanitize=address
```

Then, you need to preload libasan when running your unsanitized 
executable with

```
LD_PRELOAD=path/to/libasan.so /local/test/client_new/test_build/kkl/tools/kenzip -c dcltotb.tcl
```

Comment: Hi Yugr,Tried correcting LDFLAGS and then set LD_PRELOAD to asan.so path, When i try to create glib using 'make' . After a while it failed with '==98241==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks' error.

Comment: @santosh Nothing in my answer suggested setting `LD_PRELOAD` when running `make`. Once again: "you need to preload libasan.so when running your unsanitized executable".

Comment: i am sorry i could not get you.. Here i am just creating glib library with asan. glib creation steps :- 1) configure.... 2) make 3) make install. unsanitized executable in the sense ?

Comment: @santosh `LD_PRELOAD` needs to be set before running `kenzip`.

Comment: ,yes now i am able to run the command successfully. But is there any other alternative other than setting LD_PRELOAD ? because there are some executables in our Application which didn't run with ASAN and trying to use them. everytime Setting LD_PRELOAD is not the better option right ?

Comment: for kenzip it works fine. There is another executable 'compress' with was not ran with asan , For the 'compress' executable as well i am pre-loading asan library before running it. It is getting failed with error : -==122560==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting free on address which was not malloc()-ed: 0x0000019fd200 in thread T0

Comment: @santosh Well, that means that Asan detected a bug in `compress` executable (if you preload libasan to executable, it'll detect some types of bugs even if executable and it's libraries were not linked with asan). You need to examine the stacktrace and figure out how to fix it.

Comment: "But is there any other alternative other than setting LD_PRELOAD" - relink executables with Asan (`-fsanitize=address`) is the best option but it's not always viable (e.g. when you don't have source code of executable). "Setting LD_PRELOAD is not the better option right" - well, it makes Asan integration slightly more complicated because you need to locate all interesting executables and change them to start with `LD_PRELOAD` but it's much easier than rebuild everything with Asan.

Comment: Okay.. Setting LD_PRELOAD for few executables which are not ran with asan before running them would be fine in your opinion ?

Comment: @santosh Depends on your goals. If you are interested in bugs in these executables and can fix them, then you can set `LD_PRELOAD`. If not, better set it only for executables which link against Glib (I assume your main goal is to check Glib).

Comment: @yugur, I am not concern about the error thrown by asan for 'compress' executable. Is There any way to skip the error and continue with the build?

Comment: @santosh There [is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40305194/2170527) but it'll complicate integration even more. Better just avoid setting `LD_PRELOAD` for executables which do not need it. In particular do _not_ set `LD_PRELOAD` globally.

Comment: I am not pre loading asan library globally instead I am only setting the environment to pre load for only the targets which run executables that didn't ran with asan. Here for compress executable if i avoid pre loading the library it will fail with  undefined reference to __asan_option_detect_stack_use_after_return. Could you suggest any other alternative for fixing it?

Comment: @santosh You can try the link which I posted in previous comment (which suggests using `-fsanitize-recover=address` and `halt_on_error`). But let's not discuss it here in comments, as it's unrelated to your original question ("Building Glib library with Asan").

Answer (score 1):

Build the latest version of GLib (2.62.4). It is built using Meson, rather than autotools, and you can [enable ASAN by passing `-Db_sanitize=address` to `meson`](https://mesonbuild.com/howtox.html#use-address-sanitizer) when configuring the build.

Comment: Phiip,i am trying to create glib version 2.56, It wont possible to build asan version glib with that version? Actually , we dont want to change our glib right now.

Comment: I doubt this alone will help if OP tries linking sanitized Glib into unsanitized executable.

Comment: GLib 2.56 is unsupported and (like all old, unsupported software) has security vulnerabilities. You should aim to switch to a more up to date version of GLib soon. The side effect of switching to Meson from autotools should make a lot of common build system operations (like use of sanitisers) faster and easier.

But if you have to use GLib 2.56, then see yugr’s answers for how to build that version with sanitisers.